# FileNotFoundException while reading and printing a ppm file

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I want to write a function that receives a name of a PPM file and returns an array containing the image's data.

```
import.java.io

public class read {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][][] pic = read("test.ppm");
        StdOut.println(pic);
    }

    public static int[][][] read (String ppmfile){
        StdIn.setInput(ppmfile);
        int n = StdIn.readInt();
        int[][][] data = new int[n][n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
                    data[i][j][k] = StdIn.readInt();
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

This is the code I wrote but I get the error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.ppm (No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) at StdIn.setInput(StdIn.java:147) at read.read(read.java:10) at read.main(read.java:5)`

Comment: you would need to provide a proper path of the test.ppm

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: The file wasn't  found. What part of that don't you understand? The filename was wrong or it isn't where you said it was. Nothing to do wth the code.

Comment: The file located exactly at the same place that the code read located and this is why I don't understand the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is wrong for your file.  You can right click on the file and copy the path to get the accurate path.

Or you can use this code which will bring up a GUI window that will let you choose a file.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a file");        
JFileChooser input = new JFileChooser();
int a = input.showOpenDialog(null);
String file = "";

if (a == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = input.getSelectedFile();
    file = selectedFile.getPath();
}
```